# String.Replace does not replace Unicode Character 'ARABIC LETTERS'

Tags: c#, string, oop, unicode

I have two arrays, one that contains a set of characters to search for in a specific string and the other the set of strings with which to replace a specific character if found.

I'm trying to use the standard `String.Replace()` to modify the given string when the specific character is found. The method I'm trying to use detects that the string contains the character/characters of my array, enters the loop and runs the operation but at the end nothing is changed.

I'm not sure why or how to go to solve this. Below is my code and results.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var wordToPass = "heyك";

    wordToPass = wordToPass.MultiReplace();

    Console.WriteLine(wordToPass);
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

The extension method to replace the characters:

```
    public static class StringExtension
{
    public static readonly char[] SignsArray = new char[] { 'ك', 'ـ', 'ض', 'ؤ', 'ا', 'ط', 'ئ', 'إ', 'ر', 'أ', ' ', 'ہ', 'ء', 'ب', 'ة', 'ت', 'ز',
                                                'س', 'ص', 'ظ', 'ع', 'ج', 'ح', '´', 'ف', 'ث', '¶', '°', '؛', '·', '`' };

    public static readonly string[] RepArray = new string[] { "SS", "UE", "OE", "AE", "C", "OE", "AE", "AA", "N", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "O", "O", "O",
                                                  "U", "U", "I", "I", "'", "Y", "E", "A", ".", ".", ".", "'"};


    // Extension on String
    public static string MultiReplace(this string stringValue)
    {
        HashSet<char> set = new HashSet<char>(SignsArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < stringValue.Length; ++i)
        {
            var currentCharacter = stringValue[i];
            string valueToReplace;
            string replaceValue;
            if (set.Contains(currentCharacter))
            {
                valueToReplace = Char.ToString(stringValue[i]);
                replaceValue = RepArray[Array.IndexOf(SignsArray, currentCharacter)];
                stringValue.Replace(Convert.ToString(currentCharacter), replaceValue);
            }
        }

        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Replace` returns a new string, as `System.String` is immutable.

Consider reassigning.

```
stringValue = stringValue.Replace(Convert.ToString(currentCharacter), replaceValue);
```

Comment: Yup. Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Looked over the other question which answers this one but did not come to mind to reassign the return value of Replace. Sigh